# Is "number of times" ordinal or interval variable?

Tags: ordinal-data

For my research paper, I want to measure headache frequency and I asked participants " Since last month how many times you have had headche ? and they gave answers like 2 times, 3, 5, 10, 14 times etc.. 
I am confused with the type of this data, Shall I treat it as ordinal or interval ?

Comment: It's actually ratio scale. "4 times" is really twice "2 times". But it's discrete (since it's a count), not continuous.

Answer (score 4):

It is ordinal, because the order matters. It is also interval, because the difference between 1 and 2 is the same as that between 20 and 21 - exactly, unambiguously 1 headache. It is also a "ratio" variable, because the value of zero reflects the complete absence of the thing being measured.

An example of ordinal but not interval would be if you asked them to rate the severity of the headache. You could rank these in a meaningful order (maybe as: low, medium, high) but there is nothing intrinsic about the measurement that says the distance between low and medium is the same as that between medium and high.

EDIT: Following from Peter's comment, I realize I didn't actually answer the question: Treat it as a ratio variable.

Comment: It's also a *count* - for most analyses you might want to do it's not rescalable.

Comment: When a variable is ratio it is always ordinal and interval, so usually we simply say it is ratio. Indeed, treating a ratio (or count) variable as ordinal will often be a bad idea - classifying continuous or count variables usually is.